# What vergence angle is commonly used for "infinitely distant" objects in VR?

Tags: virtual-reality

I posted a very similar question on computer graphics stackexchange, here https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/13399/11224 a while ago, but it hasn't attracted any answers.

I think that VR / AR experts will know the answer to this.

At what vergence angle are "infinitely far away" objects such as star field textures drawn in head-mounted VR / AR displays ?

I believe I have read that the stars in the night sky are so far away that our human visual system cannot distinguish the degree of vergence required to look at them from "parallel vergence", where the view directions of the two eyes are parallel. That is, the stars are so far away that in this particular sense, they may as well be infinitely far away.

In my experiments with anaglyph displays on laptop screens, I have found that it is very uncomfortable to diverge my eyes to the point of parallel view directions, in order to resolve star field textures that are "infinitely distant", i.e., in which the left and right images are separated horizontally by exactly my interpupillary distance.

In case this might be due to measurement errors causing the separation on screen to very slightly exceed my actual interpupillary distance, I have experimented with reducing that separation one mm at a time, until the degree of vergence became tolerably comfortable. However, this required a separation difference that was significantly smaller than my actual interpupillary distance, tending to refute the "measurement errors" hypothesis.

Is the discomfort likely to be due more to the well-known contradiction between vergence and accommodation (focus) that is a drawback of conventional stereoscopic displays ?

As well as the muscular discomfort, I noticed that the star field texture was blurry, as if my eyes were refusing to focus on the screen. Perhaps at this extreme of vergence, the physiological connection between vergence and accommodation forces accommodation at infinity ?

In VR headsets, does the greater focal depth alleviate this problem, i.e. is the limit of comfort for vergence closer to parallel, in this case ?

I have read that parallel vergence should be avoided in stereoscopic displays, because it is unnatural for our visual system, but I have not read any explanation as to why (almost) parallel vergence is perfectly comfortable for viewing stars in the real world. Might it also be to do with the fact that the solid angle subtended on earth by a star in the real world is very small ?

Are some of my assumptions wrong ?

Comment: I can't answer all your questions, but authors that use geometry for the skybox often make it small (and might disable depth test for it). However, in VR, the player can notice that it's too close (see https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/152828/10408). Sadly making the geometry big enough - which also implies to increase the far rendering distance - brings z-buffer accuracy issues. Instead, see if your engine has a working sky shader/renderer solution that does rely on geometry, and use that.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment on that post, the size of a skybox's geometry does not dictate the perceived distance to its texture detail. Typically a skybox cubemap is sampled using the view direction, ignoring camera translation, which means that in terms of vergence it's infinitely far away. If you observe something different in a game, they're likely using the wrong shader — not a fundamental limitation.

Comment: Thank you Theraot. Perhaps the z-buffer issues could be helped by using a reverse-z projection matrix with an "infinite" far plane, as in Nathan Reed's blog here ? https://www.reedbeta.com/blog/depth-precision-visualized/ But perhaps game engines don't usually support this ?

Comment: Thank you DMGregory - that's very interesting. I knew about having skyboxes infinitely far away in monoscopic graphics, and I'm interested to learn from you that this is also done in both eyes, in VR headsets. When I tried it with anaglyph glasses on a monitor, it seemed to cause eye strain and focus problems. It sounds from what you say as if the focal length of a VR headset solves this problem. Would you care to make your comment an answer ?